# React Native FlatList Memory Leak

Tags: react-native, flatlist

I wondering, is react native have reusable view in each item list? like what native does. So it just alloc view that displayed in screen (ex: 5 views).
Some people said, it can be achieved by using flatlist component, but after i try by myself. all data is rendered (ex: 31 data). i print out in render function and all data be log even my screen just can display 5 items.

Answer (score 1):

By default FlatList renders only 10 items, you can control it with `initialNumToRender`. In your case probably you have some implementations issues, like providing an anonymous function to `renderItem`. More cases you can find here https://www.obytes.com/blog/a-guide-to-optimizing-flatlists-in-react-native

Also, you can try FlashList from Shopify https://github.com/shopify/flash-list
It has a similar API to FlatList but works much better with performance and memory. Documentation is here https://shopify.github.io/flash-list/docs/usage/